# Python solve given conditions

Tags: python, matrix, solver, determinants

everyone

Is it possible to solve the following like:

```
x = np.matrix([[8.3,-20.6],[-20.6,65.8]])
```

y is a function of P:

```
y = lambda P: np.matrix([[0.02P,-0.02P], [-0.02P,0.04P]])
```

I want to find the P value given conditions that:

```
P>0, det(x-y)==0;
```

Is there any handy way for this?

Thank you very much!
Shawn

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an additional package, scipy.optimize has a number of methods that would be perfect. Otherwise, you could [implement your own zero finding function](http://danielhomola.com/2016/02/09/newtons-method-with-10-lines-of-python/).

If you want to go the scipy route:

1) Define your problem as a function that takes your unknown parameter (P) as its first argument, and returns the value you want to minimize:

```
def zerofn(P, x, y):
    return np.linalg.det(x - y(P))
```

2) Optimize this function, using scipy. The example here uses a simple Newton-Raphson zero finder, but there are [many other options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.html) which you might want to use to specify parameter bounds (e.g. P > 0).

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

opt.newton(zerofn, x0=1, args=(x, y))

>> 160.25865914054651
```

The result of this zero finder is your optimized value of P.

Comment: Thank you so much Oscar!

Comment: No worries - happy to help!